# Could not find HTTP Proxy Server option in workbench > Add > Non-Test Elements in jMeter version 2.12

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to learn Performance Testing using JMeter.  I have installed JMeter 2.12 version on my machine. Now I want to set up the Proxy using option HTTP Proxy Server which is under Workbench. But I could not find HTTP Proxy Server, option anywhere. Could you please help me?

Comment: have you check the jmeter user guide? the link is http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html

Comment: It should under workbench -> Add -> Non-Test elements. If you still cannot see it then re-download the binaries/zip and try again.

Answer (score 4):

The test element you're looking for is now called [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

You can also get things done faster and easier using [Recording Template](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

Click File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create and JMeter will automatically populate test plan and workbench structure ready for recording.

N.B. Proxy port is "8888" for template-generated plan.